# Why does the Quantum Approximate Optimization Algorithm work?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, algorithms

I am trying to understand the structure of the QAOA algorithm (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.4028)) which is seen as one of the candidates to demonstrate early quantum supremacy. Yet Farhi, Goldstone and Gutmann only describe the algorithm but not supply an intuition why it works (why it finds the approximate optimum to a combinatorial problem). Can anyone explain the idea behind the algorithm to me? (I.e. why do I use the angles and maximize with respect to them?)

Comment: The algorithm uses the fact the unitary has integer eigenvalues, so the unitary they have constructed approximate the solution, in the first place, then successively concentrate to approximate the solution.